# What code is responsible for inserting "Miscellaneous Scripts" / Troubleshooting

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, magento-1, template, troubleshooting

I'm troubleshooting a site that has code inserted into the "Miscellaneous Scripts" (`System -> Configuration -> Design -> HTML Head`)but it is not being displayed on the frontend of the site.

If I view page source there is nothing from the `Miscellaneous Scripts` portion, however if I edit `head.phtml` and insert the code directly it appears immediately.

My question is, **what code is responsible for inserting the scripts  into the head portion (presumably I could copy and paste the code into the `head.phtml`?)and what could cause the script not to appear at all?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code responsible is `getIncludes()` defined in `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head`:

```
public function getIncludes()
{
    if (empty($this->_data['includes'])) {
        $this->_data['includes'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/includes');
    }
    return $this->_data['includes'];
}
```

And called in `head.phtml`:

```
echo $this->getIncludes();
```

A possible cause is that the miscellaneous scripts are empty when you switch the config to the store view.

Edit: seems like the real cause was that a module was rewriting `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head`

Comment: Okay I dont have `echo $this->getIncludes();` anywhere in `head.phtml` and the code is present.

Comment: @SR_Magento try to run `grep -r "$this->getIncludes()" .` on your magento root folder. Also try `grep -r "design/head/includes" .`

Comment: Okay it is there in the head (guess I missed it) so now I need to know why its not displaying.

Comment: @SR_Magento as I say it could be because the field is empty when you change scope to the store view in the config and the Use Default Value checkbox is unticked

Comment: The script contents are there for each store view. Is there possibly a core module that could be disabled responsible?

Comment: @SR_Magento try to type `echo get_class($this)` in `head.phtml` to find out if the Head block is getting rewritten

Comment: Genius, looks like a module for SEO is responsible - thank you!!!

Comment: @SR_Magento you're welcome ;)